# Duvida com PHP e textarea

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

tudo blz?

Estou com um pequeno problema. 
Tenho que enviar um texto com parágrafos e quebras de linhas, via php pro bd, e em outra página chamar o texto com os parágrafos e as quebras de linhas corretas, o que eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo você trabalhar com alguma biblioteca javascript que faça a formatação da string([Tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/)). Em seguida, faça o processo normal de inserção/edição. Já no BD, apenas crie um campo na tabela com tipo text

Comment: me tira só mais uma dúvida, como eu deixo pra ele permitir plano de fundo?

Comment: Não entendi. Como assim plano de fundo ?